# MySQL, how can I speed up this query which takes 1.4 second?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

How can I speed up this query ?

```
SELECT PadID, CatID, IconSoureURL, OsStr, PadURL, PageName, ProgramName,  
ProgramVersion, ReleaseStatus, English45, License, DownloadURL
FROM Pads
WHERE RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC
LIMIT 360 , 40
```

I already have an index, heres the query explained .

[image]

Comment: please include - `show index from Pads;`

Comment: what is the type of RemoveMeDate

Comment: please include `SHOW COLUMNS FROM Pads` so that we can see column types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an index on RemoveMeDate and VersionDate
`CREATE INDEX new_index ON (RemoveMeDate, VersionDate);`
you must ensure that the order by is done on a index ( index on RemoveMeDate and VersionDate  should do that - RemoveMeDate part of the index will be used by where and VersionDate part of the index will be used by order by)

Comment: Try to create the index on both columns and run explain if your 'using filesort' part will disappear from `EXTRA` column - thats a progress

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on RemoveMeDate though?

Answer (score 0):

VersionAddDate should have index, not good to sort on non-indexed column.